# Create an on click event handler for an array of Radiobuttons

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have created an array of radiobuttons, which will be created in an event. I want to create an event, saying to make the radiobutton invisible when it is clicked and the show a message. But it has to happen on click. Can you help me?
This is how I created my radiobuttons

```
for k := 1 to 20 do
begin
  rd[k] := TRadioButton.Create(Self);
  rd[k].Parent := pgcVerkiesing;
  rd[k].Caption := 'rs'+IntToStr(k);
  rd[k].Left := 16;
  if k = 1 then
    rd[k].Top := 26
  else
    rd[k].Top := (k*24) ;
  rd[k].OnClick := OnClick;
end;
```

Now I want to do something like this :   `rs1.clicked //procedure`

```
rs1.disabled := true;
richedit1.lines.add := 'Name';
showmessage(names);
```

What to do?

Comment: Please try and be clear and precise about what you want.The final code sample does not remotely compile and it's not clear in what context you want it to execute.

Comment: The answer was 100% accurate and did exactly what I wanted it to do. Tankx

Comment: That's as maybe. The question was unclear and the code you posted was vague and inaccurate. If you got a good answer then you got lucky. Don't take that fact that @LURD was able decipher your question as indication that it was a good question. Notice also that the question had to be edited by others to make it legible. I am offering constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to disable the clicked radiobutton.

Define an event for your radiobuttons:

```
procedure TForm1.OnRadioButtonClick(Sender : TObject);
```

When creating your radiobuttons, tie this event handler to the radiobuttons.

```
rd[k].OnClick := OnRadioButtonClick;
```

---

```
procedure TForm1.OnRadioButtonClick(Sender : TObject);
begin
  TRadioButton(Sender).Enabled := false;
  RichEdit1.Lines.Add( 'Name');
  ShowMessage( names);  // names not defined ??
end;
```

Comment: I guess you need OnClick on the buttons. "For a form, an OnClick event occurs when the user clicks a disabled component or in a blank area of the form."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you are right. I thought this was too obvious. Added explicit `OnRadioButtonClick` event.

Comment: Next remove the loop since Sender is the button in question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I need more coffee :-)

Comment: Better. Who knows what RichEdit1.Lines.Add( 'Name') is meant to do?

Comment: I bet `TRadioButton(Sender).Caption` is the intended string, but we can only guess.

Comment: @user2399561, did this answer solve your problem? If so, read [`faq#howtoask`](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to learn how to accept an answer.